# Shopware6 change search logic

Tags: elasticsearch, shopware6

I am part of a team building a shopware6 solution connected to an elastic search engine. The search functionality is not meeting customers needs and I am trying to change it.

If I search ABC123
I only want results containing the exact phrase eg:

- ABC123xxx
- xxxABC123
- xxxABC123xxx

With the existing search functionality i am getting all sorts of more or less related results.

It does not seem to have any impact when changing search settings in shopware. I have no clue where to start so bear with me:) All help is much appreciated.

KR.